# component is not rendered when Route is defined inside Menu component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to create reusable menu component which will be totally based on react-router. I could show the menu items but when clicked, the component that need to be rendered is not rendered. But if i define routes outside of menu component like inside `<Router>` component it works. How can i make it work on either way?

Here is how i have done

Menu.js

```
const Menu = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header padding>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <NavTabs>{children}</NavTabs>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Header>
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

MenuItem.js

```
const MenuItem = ({ to, children, match }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink to={`${match.path}${to}`}>{children}</NavLink>
      </NavItem>
    </>
  );
};

export default withRouter(MenuItem);
```

This is how I am using it

```
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "Home", path: "home", component: HomeC },
  { id: 2, name: "Jobs", path: "jobs", component: Jobs }
];

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      Menu
      <Menu>
        {items.map(item => (
          <MenuItem key={item.id} to={item.path}>
            {item.name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
        {/* if Route is defined inside Menu component, render component from here only else from outside */}
        <>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/home" component={HomeC} />
            <Route path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
          </Switch>
        </>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is the full code with demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/vq0w113140

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your index.js, your router is not matching any of the Routes for `/jobs`.

```
  <Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/hello" render={() => <h1>Hello</h1>} />
    <Route path="/home" render={() => <h1>Hello</h1>} />
  </Router>
```

You'll need to add a route here for `/jobs`, or if you'd like to default the `Home` component, wrap the routes in a `Switch` and add a `Route` with no `path=` at the bottom, with the `component={Home}` option.

---

**EDIT** - Switch example

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/hello" render={() => <h1>Hello</h1>} />
        <Route path="/home" render={() => <h1>Hello</h1>} />
        <Route component={Home} />
    <Switch>
</Router>
```

With this example, any route other than `/hello` and `/home` will render the Home component. A switch works much like a `switch` in code would - it will pick the first one from the list that matches, and render that. If none match, it will render the last item in the list.

This would allow you to render the Jobs component with the job routes inside the Home component, to include the menu.

Comment: I did not understand `f you'd like to default the Home component` part. Can you show me an example for this, please?

Comment: Yeah, most people use Switch's last option for some kind of custom 404 page, but you could include that in the Switch inside the `Home` component so you still show the menu etc on a 404 page

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Routes from Menu.js

and place them in the index.js just below the Home Component Route.

you can use this code:

Home.js:

```
  const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      Menu
      <Menu>
        {items.map(item => (
          <MenuItem key={item.id} to={item.path}>
            {item.name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
        {/* if Route is defined inside Menu component, render component from here only else from outside */}
        <></>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};
```

index.js:
`please remove exact in first route`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/jobs" render={() => <h1>jobs component</h1>} />
        <Route path="/home" render={() => <h1>Home component</h1>} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the working code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pjx7pv581j

Comment: cannot i show which component to render for following path just inside Menu as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Switch` from `react-router-dom`. `Switch` returns only one first matching route.

```
function App() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Here is my solution: https://codesandbox.io/embed/wn4j5525n8